# 2D Parametric plots in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a parametric parabola given by x(t)=125cos(30)t and y(t)=3+125sin(30)t-16t^2

Here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[blue, samples=40, variable=\t, domain=0:4]
    ({125*t*cos(deg(30)))},
    {3+125*t*sin(deg(30))-16*t^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This is what i get:

[image]

And this is what I'm after [image]

Comment: Your code has an `x^2` in it. Is it supposed to be `t^2`?

Comment: I was about to freak out, but i changed it and it didnt help

Comment: What _did_ you get as an output?

Comment: I just edited my original post. unfortunaly i dont know how to generate the graph without converting the whole page to a .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few (possible) problems with your code:

1. By issuing `domain=0:4` you are telling TikZ to plot between `t = 0` and `t = 4`. It appears from your desired output you want to plot between approximately `x = 0` and `x=4`.
2. By issuing `deg(30)` you are *not* plotting cosine and sine of 30 degrees; instead you are plotting cosine and sine of 30 radians. (The `deg` function converges *from* radians *to* degrees; TikZ's trigonometry functions assume its arguments are in degrees.)

---

Sanity check: cosine of 30 radians is 0.154, mulitplied by 4 times 125 gives 77.13 which matches very well with the upper bound of what you observed to be the output.

---

To get the plot you want, you probably want to remove the calls to `deg` (since I am pretty sure you don't want something bizarre like 30 radians). And you should also change your domain to something like `0:0.05` which would give upper and lower bounds for x to be approximately 0 to 5.

Comment: So, removing deg() totally worked; however, i had to keep the domain at 0:4 as i need t to go to 4. Thank you for the help, and just to clarify—using deg() converts the number to radian? What if i were to use a variable such as deg(x)?

Comment: No: in TikZ when you type `sin(x)` it is expected that `x` is the angle in degrees. If you want to use radian values, you have to first convert the radian value `r` to degrees by issuing `deg(r)`. So `deg(2*pi)` is equal to `360`. (In other words, `deg` is a function that takes input a radian angle measure and outputs the equivalent degree measure.)