# How to draw a maple leaf in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[This blog](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/how-to-draw-with-math/) shows some math parametrized functions that can be used to "plot" symmetric leaves like the one below:

[image]

Is it possible to implement such functions and draw the leaf using Ti*k*Z?

Comment: Probably. Can you? Or is this a do-it-all-for-me without even the it?

Comment: I can't draw it.

Comment: @Thumbolt, now perhaps you can't. Though what crf probably means is should you *try* to do it then one day you'll be able to draw it. If you never try you never will. `:)`

Comment: I was reading the pgfplots example gallery but I was unable to find an example that has x(t)=, y(t)=  ... of that kind.

Comment: @Thumbolt, wrong source of Information. Try [this one](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) if you can't find it there then Houston we have a problem!

Comment: There are several questions about parametric plots here on the site, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319739/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65719/plotting-parametric-curves/65732#65732 [and more](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=parametric+plot)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply based on rpapa's answer and the formulas in the question, here is a working .tex file which can be compiled with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[scale=3, domain=0:180, variable=\t, samples=500, fill=red]
plot (%
{
(
1
+
(cos(6*\t))^2
+
(1/5)*(cos(6*\t)*cos(24*\t))^10
+
( (1/4)*(cos(30*\t))^2 + (1/9)*(cos(30*\t))^12) *  (1-(sin(6*\t))^10)
)
*(sin(2*\t))
*(1-(cos(\t))^4)
*(1 - (cos(\t))^10 * (cos(3*\t))^2)
+(1/70)*(cos(\t))^9
}
,
{
(-21/20)*cos(2*\t)*(1 - (cos(\t))^4 + (1/2)*(cos(\t)*cos(3*\t))^10)
*
(
1
+
(cos(6*\t))^2
+
(1/5)*(cos(6*\t)*cos(18*\t))^10
+
( (1/4)*(cos(30*\t))^4 + (1/10)*(cos(30*\t))^12 )
*
( 1 - ((cos(\t))^10) * (cos(3*\t))^2 )
*
( 1 - (sin(6*\t))^10 )
)
}
);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I left in my original line-breaks and potentially unnecessary parentheses.

Notes:

I recommend qtikz or ktikz on GNU/Linux to easily preview TikZ pictures.

Also, when copying the formulas, make sure to always add a "*" between numbers and "\t". I am not sure why it is necessary, but TikZ seems to read things like "6\t" wrong without giving any errors.

[image: Maple leaf generated with TikZ]

[image: red Maple leaf generated with TikZ]

Comment: Very nice rendering.

Comment: Can we color this leaf?

Comment: Yes, we can! Simply add ",fill=red" for example to the \draw command. Check the tikz documentation for more infos. :)

Answer (score 18):

Oak Leaf only with basic function of Tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[scale=3,domain=0:180,variable=\t, samples=500]
plot (%
{1/100*(cos(\t))^9*(cos(5*\t))^10 +1/4*sin(2*\t)*(1-1/2*(sin(10*\t))^2)*(1-(cos(\t)*cos(3*\t))^8)
},{
sin(\t)*(1-1/5*(sin(10*\t)^2*(1/2+(sin(2*\t)^2)
});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But if you are from Canada, an oak leaf just won't do....